# When I start a new game on Pokemon OR, will I be able to create a new Game Sync ID on the same DS game card?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire, pokemon-bank

Can you re-submit the Pokémon you have caught with the new account to the bank as well, or is it better to just buy Sapphire if I am trying to have both as a savored account? Will I be able to create another game sync ID with the same DS card, so that I could save my newly caught Pokémon into the bank? How does this work?

Comment: @Ealhad Easy on the edits.  You're flooding the main page, for nothing more than an accent change.  Nothing wrong with updating one or two, but try not to take over the whole front page.

Comment: @Frank Duely noted.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be given a new (generated) Game Sync ID if you make a new save game. However, you will be able to re-submit (store) your Pokémon with the new save game into the same PokéBank, as long as you're using the same physical Nintendo 3DS. You can also buy Sapphire and store Pokémon into the same PokéBank, if you wish. And you'll be able to freely withdraw the Pokémon too.

[Source](http://pokemondb.net/spinoff/pokemon-bank)